# Jquery dialog with transfer effect issue

Tags: jquery

some how i manage to have jquery transfer effect working with jquery dialog but there is one glitch. here is the url http://jsbin.com/amicev/2 please go and see. the glitch is when dialog appear then dialog appear before the transfer effect complete. i want that dialog should appear after transfer effect complete. if i try to write the code for showing dialog after the completion of transfer effect.

### so here is my full code

```
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
.ui-effects-transfer {
border: 2px dotted grey;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="btnToggle" value="Toggle Dialog">
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display: none">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

 jQuery(function($) {
// Set up the dialog, don't show it yet
// Note the effects, they tie up with the
// transfer effect we do later.
 $("#dialog").dialog({
 show: {
  effect:   "fade",
  duration: 1000
},
hide: {
  effect:   "fade",
  duration: 500
},
autoOpen: false
});

// Hook up the button to toggle showing/hiding
// the dialog
$("#btnToggle").click(function() {
var dlg = $("#dialog");

// Show or hide?
if (dlg.is(":visible")) {
  // Hide: Kick off the transfer effect and close the
  // dialog. The transfer will run simultaneously
  // with the fade we configured above
  dlg.effect("transfer", {
    to: "#btnToggle",
    className: "ui-effects-transfer",
    duration: 500
  }).dialog("close");
 }
 else {
  // Show: Show the dialog, then kick off a transfer
  // effect transferring the button to the dialog's
  // widget. Again the transfer and fade run simultaneously
  // and so work together.
  dlg.dialog("open");
  $(this).effect("transfer", {
    to: dlg.dialog("widget"),
    className: "ui-effects-transfer"
  }, 500);
}
return false;
});
});
```

if i try to modify this line to appear dialog after transfer effect complete then output is getting distorted.

```
     $(this).effect("transfer", {
     to: dlg.dialog("widget"),
     className: "ui-effects-transfer"
     }, 500,function() { dlg.dialog("open"); });
```

so i just want to show dialog after completion of transfer effect. so tell me what i need to change in the code as a result output should not distorted.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have seen firsthand, you cannot reliably trigger the `transfer` effect if the dialog widget is hidden through `display: none;` (since the widget's dimensions cannot be measured under these conditions).

However, you can set its [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility) property to `hidden`, trigger the effect, then set the property back to `visible`. This gives good results in my tests:

```
  dlg.dialog("open").dialog("widget").css("visibility", "hidden");
  $(this).effect("transfer", {
      to: dlg.dialog("widget"),
      className: "ui-effects-transfer"
  }, 500, function() {
      dlg.dialog("widget").css("visibility", "visible");
  });
```

You will find an updated JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/amicev/5/).

Comment: thanks it works. tell me another issue that when closing dialog then i first need to close dialog and then transfer effect should start. i did it like dlg.dialog("close");
      dlg.effect("transfer", {
        to: "#btnToggle",
        className: "ui-effects-transfer",
        duration: 500
      }); but still it seems dialog that two routine execute at a time but i want to hide dialog first and when dialog completely vanish then transfer animation should start. so please have a look at my code and tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try applying the strategy in my answer in reverse? First set the dialog widget's visibility to `hidden`, then trigger the effect, then close the dialog?

Comment: thanks it works but please visit the url http://jsbin.com/amicev/5/edit#source if anything wrong or anything can be better. please tell me the code is ok?

Comment: If you're looking for advice on coding style or efficiency improvements, I'd recommend you post a new question on our [codereview.se] sister site (as such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow).

Comment: i run the script in IE8 but it says error. can u please run it in IE8. the error message is not clear. the same code works fine in FF & chrome.

Comment: simply test the code for IE & FF then u see the difference when dialog appear. what would be the good fix? plzz help

Comment: I ran the code on IE8 (8.0.6001.18702) and I see no error and no difference in behavior when showing the dialog. Maybe the problem is related to an IE add-on you installed?